# Read strings in c in if instruction

Tags: c, string, if-statement

I have a problem with reading strings in c. When I add the gets() function in an if-instruction, the program stops.

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    int n,i = 0;
    char sir[2000],ch;

    printf("Press you option: "); scanf("%d",&n);

    if(n == 1)
    {
        printf("text: "); gets(sir);

        printf("\nINPUT: ");
        for(i = 0;i < strlen(sir);i++)
            printf("%c",sir[i]);

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Any solution?

Comment: [DO NOT use `gets()`, it is dangerous](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1694036/2173917). use [`fgets()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets) instead.

Comment: `stopping`..please elaborate.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/dr2j5r , when i read 1, the program stoped, i try with fgets()
EDIT:  i can use fgets() becouse i need to read from keyboard, not from file

Comment: `gets(sir);` --> `scanf(" %1999[^\n]", sir);`

Comment: BLUEPIXY it's work :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I add the gets() function in an if-instruction, the program stops.

Look at the preceding code.  Maybe you entered <kbd>1</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd>

```
printf("Press you option: "); 
scanf("%d",&n);
```

`scanf("%d",&n);` consume the `'1'`, but not the `'\n'`.
Later code  does

```
printf("text: "); 
gets(sir);
```

And then `gets()` reads that `'\n'` and returns with `sir[0] == '\0'`, an *empty* string.  This causes `for(i = 0;i < strlen(sir);i++)` to not iterate the body of the `for()` loop.

---

What to do?

Read a *line* of user input  `fgets()` and then process that string.  Note that invalid input, EOF and buffer overflow handling not addressed in this simple code example.   That would be step 2.

```
char buf[80];
printf("Press you option: "); 
fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin);
sscanf(buf, "%d",&n);

printf("text: "); 
fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin);
buf[strcspn(buf, "\n")] = '\0'; // lop off potential \n
strcpy(sir, buf);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the C input buffer problem, just add one getchar() as shown, it will work, let me know for any other help.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
  int n,i = 0;
  char sir[2000],ch;

  printf("Press you option: "); scanf("%d",&n);

  if(n == 1)
  {
    printf("text: ");
    getchar();
    gets(sir);

    printf("\nINPUT: ");
    for(i = 0;i < strlen(sir);i++)
        printf("%c",sir[i]);

 }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: This answer still uses `gets` tough, one should not ignore compiler warnings. (And if your compiler does not warn against `gets` consider upgrading).

Comment: The warning is because gets is very bad at handling overflow errors, one needs to handle it. Else to avoid warning can use scanf("%s", sir); but it will truncate everything after a space.

Comment: @ShirshenduBhowmick `gets()` **and**  `scanf("%s", sir)` are both equally bad at handling buffer overflows.  Neither should be used.

Comment: Yes, but  @unimportant was talking about the warning, what i did was just solved the buffer problem by adding `getchar()`, as @Gradin98 asked only about it.

Comment: @chux is there any reason why one should not use scanf like =>> scanf("%SIZEs", buffer); ?

Comment: @Michi `scanf("%SIZEs", buffer);` is OK.  Weakness: Return value not checked, general complexities/problems about `scanf()`, potential consuming leading white-space when not expected.  But yes, that does fix the buffer overflow problem.  C's inputs functions, as a whole have weakness, but used as building blocks, can be used well.

Comment: @chux I will not check the return value of scanf in a comment :)), more over when is about scanf itself and not about its return value. I'm agree that I need some other tweaks to make scanf work when it comes to white spaces, I'll probably use fgets here. Scanf is not wrong or bad it is only that almost always used wrong. By the way, happy New Year!

Comment: @michi  Yes  `scanf()`  is too often used wrong.  Perhaps "[Jessica scanf()](http://www.imdb.com/character/ch0008316/quotes)" would say "I'm not bad.. I'm just drawn that way"?

Comment: @chux you definitely made my day whit that :))

Comment: @Gradin98 What would you want to happen to indicate _no input_ into `sir`?  `scanf(" %1999[^\n]", sir);` will not work in that case, it will not return, waiting for non-white-space input.  If you wanted to enter 3 spaces into `sir` , that `scanf()` will not work either.  Perhaps these matter, perhaps not.  The post is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

gets() is not preferred way to get the input from the user these days. As mentioned above please use fgets to read the input.

Coming back to your problem. Please fflush(stdin) in order to resolve your issue. Trying running the below code. i have just added fflush(stdin) and now the user input is taken by fgets() and no program stopping happens.

## Code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
int n, i = 0;
char sir[2000], ch;
printf("Press you option: "); scanf("%d", &n);
if (n == 1)
{
printf("text: ");
fflush(stdin);
gets(sir);
printf("\nINPUT: ");
for (i = 0; i < strlen(sir); i++)
printf("%c", sir[i]);
}
return 0;
}
```

Also please read and understand why we are using fflush and why we need to avoid gets() function going forward. Hope i have helped you. Thank you :)

Comment: Do NOT `fflush(stdin)` : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979209/using-fflushstdin